# New dataframe based on calculations on a existing one

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm learning data analysis with R and trying to create a new dataframe based on **calculations on an existing one**. Basically, I want to show the **average** of each of the columns (starting from the column 'Media Distancia') and also another dataframe showing the **difference (subtraction)** between the last row and the first one **of each column** (not including the header of course). I'm using `dplyr`.

[This is the table](https://data.renfe.com/dataset/indicadores-de-calidad-percibida-servicios-de-obligaciones-de-servicio-publico/resource/925b74e1-a3fe-4dbf-8932-df81cc5ffc40) I'm working with, I've imported the csv as a dataframe already.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a self contained question.

Comment: In order for your question to have a better chance of getting relevant solutions, you need to provide a reproducible piece of your data as well as how you would like your output to be.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you have in mind:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  summarise(across(`Media Distancia`:`Cercanías Zaragoza`, ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))


# A tibble: 1 x 13
  `Media Distancia` `Cercanías Madri~ `Rodalies Cataluña (Núc~ `Cercanías Astur~ `Cercanías Bilb~
              <dbl>             <dbl>                    <dbl>             <dbl>            <dbl>
1              238.              257.                     220.              265.             244.
# ... with 8 more variables: Cercanías Cádiz <dbl>, Cercanías Málaga <dbl>,
#   Cercanías Murcia-Alicante <dbl>, Cercanías San Sebastian <dbl>, Cercanías Santander <dbl>,
#   Cercanías Sevilla <dbl>, Cercanías Valencia <dbl>, Cercanías Zaragoza <dbl>


df %>%
  arrange(desc(Año)) %>%
  summarise(across(`Media Distancia`:`Cercanías Zaragoza`, ~ last(.x) - first(.x)))


# A tibble: 1 x 13
  `Media Distancia` `Cercanías Madri~ `Rodalies Cataluña (Núc~ `Cercanías Astur~ `Cercanías Bilb~
              <dbl>             <dbl>                    <dbl>             <dbl>            <dbl>
1              -614              -636                     -541              -656             -590
# ... with 8 more variables: Cercanías Cádiz <dbl>, Cercanías Málaga <dbl>,
#   Cercanías Murcia-Alicante <dbl>, Cercanías San Sebastian <dbl>, Cercanías Santander <dbl>,
#   Cercanías Sevilla <dbl>, Cercanías Valencia <dbl>, Cercanías Zaragoza <dbl>
```

**Data**

```
structure(list(`_id` = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), Año = c(2019, 
2018, 2017, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2013), `Media Distancia` = c(683, 
697, 71, 7, 71, 71, 69), `Cercanías Madrid` = c(713, 719, 74, 
73, 74, 72, 77), `Rodalies Cataluña (Núcleo de Barcelona)` = c(603, 
621, 62, 63, 62, 66, 62), `Cercanías Asturias` = c(732, 746, 
74, 77, 74, 77, 76), `Cercanías Bilbao` = c(665, 691, 68, 71, 
68, 68, 75), `Cercanías Cádiz` = c(79, 729, 72, 74, 72, 74, 86
), `Cercanías Málaga` = c(771, 763, 78, 79, 78, 77, 81), `Cercanías Murcia-Alicante` = c(67, 
699, 71, 7, 71, 67, 78), `Cercanías San Sebastian` = c(726, 665, 
73, 71, 74, 71, 69), `Cercanías Santander` = c(737, 714, 74, 
73, 74, 77, 74), `Cercanías Sevilla` = c(731, 75, 68, 73, 68, 
68, 77), `Cercanías Valencia` = c(633, 644, 7, 69, 7, 69, 73), 
    `Cercanías Zaragoza` = c(767, 753, 72, 74, 72, 75, 89), Feve = c("6,6", 
    "6,5", "6,8", "6,6", "6,8", "6,6", "-")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(`_id` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Año = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `Media Distancia` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector")), `Cercanías Madrid` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector")), `Rodalies Cataluña (Núcleo de Barcelona)` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector")), `Cercanías Asturias` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector")), `Cercanías Bilbao` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector")), `Cercanías Cádiz` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector")), `Cercanías Málaga` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector")), `Cercanías Murcia-Alicante` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector")), `Cercanías San Sebastian` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector")), `Cercanías Santander` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector")), `Cercanías Sevilla` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector")), `Cercanías Valencia` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector")), `Cercanías Zaragoza` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector")), Feve = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```